# apt-get fails with following error linux-headers-3.2.0-58-generic' contains empty filename

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

> Preconfiguring packages ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package libc-ares2.
>   (Reading database ... 85%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
>    files list file for package `linux-headers-3.2.0-58-generic' contains empty filename
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

this is ubuntu with amd64 dual boot with win7. this error seems to have started when i tryed to use sun jdk instead of open jdk. thanks, tim

Answer (score 3):

This problem happens when a file list of a package gets corrupt.  to fix:

`cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm {package with problems}.list`

in your case {package with problems} would be linux-headers-3.2.0-58-generic.
The next time you run dpkg, you will get something like

```
dpkg: Warning: list file for linux-headers-3.2.0-58-generic are missing package assumed to not be installed
```

Assuming you don't get any more

`files list contains empty filename`

errors, you can do

`sudo apt-get install {package with problems}`

And apt-get install the other files with issues, and your problem should be fixed.

This is the manual way to remove a corrupt list file and reinstall the affected packages.

**Edit:** you might want to use

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall`

instead of just

`sudo apt-get install`

My information might be a bit old because I am using trisquel 7, a derivative of trusty ubuntu, which isn't the total latest, but most of the commands are the same, or just require replacing `apt-get` with `aptitude`

Answer (score 0):

you have to open up the status file in the var/lib/dpkg and delete the entry for the whole package that is referenced as failing. http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1232143.html
i also had to aptitude reinstall tzdata-java